# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number [string:Exception:private]

Tags: php, mysql

> PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => HY093 [file:protected] => /home/unfed/public_html/src/php/auth/login.php [line:protected] => 74 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /home/unfed/public_html/src/php/auth/login.php [line] => 74 [function] => execute [class] => PDOStatement [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [:username] => test ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /home/unfed/public_html/src/php/auth/login.php [line] => 137 [function] => query [args] => Array ( [0] => INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,image) VALUES (:username,:password,:email,'test') [1] => Array ( [:username] => test ) [2] => Array ( [:password] => test ) [3] => Array ( [:email] => Theres an email here ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => /home/unfed/public_html/signup/index.php [line] => 53 [function] => register [args] => Array ( [0] => test [1] => Theres an email here [2] => test ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [errorInfo] => Array ( [0] => HY093 ) )

Dont have a clue why this is happening.
Heres my PHP:

```
//Create a new function named LoggedIn, And apply database info;
function Connect($host = 'localhost',$username = 'unfed_admin',$password = 'x',$dbname = 'unfed_auth') {

    //Try execute the PHP with no errors;
    try {

        //Create a PDO Session;
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        //Session Attributes;
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    }

    //Catch all PDOException errors;
    catch (PDOException $e) {

        //If any errors print result;
        echo "<code><pre>".print_r($e)."</pre></code>";

        //Make the PDO session false;
        $con = false;
    }

    //If no errors happened Make the PDO session true;
    return $con;
}
//Create a new function named query;
function query($sql = false,$bind = false,$obj = false) {

    //Prepare The SQL Query;
    $query = Connect()->prepare($sql);

    $res = true;

    //Execute Binded Query;
    try { $query->execute($bind); $res = true; }

    catch (PDOException $e) { 

        //If any errors print result;
        echo "<code><pre>".print_r($e)."</pre></code>";

        $res = false;

    }

    //If no errors happened Make $row true;
    return $res;

}
//Create a new function named user_login;
function register($username = false, $email = false, $password = false) {

    global $registeroutput;

    //Fetch for the username and email to see if they are already used;
    $fetchusername = fetch("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username",array(":username"=>$username));
    $fetchemail = fetch("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email",array(":email"=>$email));
    if(empty($fetchusername)) {

        if(empty($fetchemail)) {

            //Register the user;
            query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,image) VALUES (:username,:password,:email,'test')",array(":username"=>$username),array(":password"=>$password),array(":email"=>$email));
            $registeroutput = 'Success';

        } else { $registeroutput = 'Email Error'; }

    } else { $registeroutput = 'Username Error'; }

    //If no errors happened Make the $valid true;
    return true;

}
```

Ignore the comment tags on the PHP code haven't updated them to be related. I have 0 clue why this is happening.

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know I use that. Just understand that isnt related. Im looking to find out why it will not instert the Email Password and Username into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a bit in the array here, causing the mismatched parameters when your query is *supposed* to be prepared:

```
query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,image) VALUES (:username,:password,:email,'test')",array(":username"=>$username),array(":password"=>$password),array(":email"=>$email));
```

In order to fix that you could make the following changes:

```
query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,image) VALUES (:username,:password,:email,:image)",array(":username"=>$username),array(":password"=>$password),array(":email"=>$email), array(":image"=>'test'));
```

Note `:image` is used in the `VALUES` clause and then added to the array.

Comment: That wasnt the issue but it lend me onto the right track there are meant to be only one array() just have all the :image etc in one array. Thanks!